# Using regex in Python 3.9 to extract text (encoded in 'johab' encoding) between known delimiters

Tags: python, encoding, io, hex, decoding

I am trying to extract extract text (encoded in 'johab' encoding) between known delimiters [see bellow]. Ideally I want to dump all the extracted text into a text file.

[Here is a screenshot of my hex editor in Johab clearly displaying the Hangeul characters properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hpy2.png)
Text always begins with "\v" (hex: 5C 76) and ends with a new line "\n" (hex: 5C 6E) or "\e".

I've used this same snippet of code to extract text between a set of bytes in the past and it worked without problems... this time I am getting an error when I decode the text using johab... I know for a fact that it is encoded in johab so I don't understand why this is happening. Of course I can ignore the errors with a try and pass but then it seems like it is failing to decode everything.
**UnicodeDecodeError: 'johab' codec can't decode byte 0x97 in position 1: illegal multibyte sequence**

```
import re

with open(path_to_file,'rb') as data: #open file filename in read mode
    buffer = data.read()#read content

text = re.findall(b'\\x5C\\x76(.*)\\x5C', buffer, re.MULTILINE)
print ("DECODING...")

for i in range(len(text)):
  #try:
    text[i] = text[i].decode('johab')
  #except:
  #  pass

print("DECODING COMPLETE.\nEXPORTING TO LOGS...")
print (text)
with open(output_path, 'w', encoding='johab') as f:
    for item in text:
        f.write("%s\n" % item)

print("EXPORTING COMPLETE.")
```

Comment: The `.*` in regex is greedy. It will match everything up to the last 0x5C byte in the buffer. Try `.*?` instead.

Comment: @MichaelButscher, just did. Still getting the illegal multibyte sequence decode error.

Comment: In addition to using `.*?`, replace `re.MULTILINE` with `re.DOTALL`. helps?

Comment: DOTALL did the trick ;) thank you